# correct way for taking time

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction

I want to reply to my professor by email. I want to ask him to give me a week to read more, and I also want to tell him I found a basic paper. Is *basic* correct in these sentences? I want to say the main paper all other papers referred to. How about:

> I found a basic paper for this.

Also, how should I ask for more time?

> I want to take one week time to learn more about this.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! I polished the grammar in your question a little bit. Can you check if the content of your main questions haven't changed? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the main paper all other papers referred to.

This is often called a *seminal* paper. This is the 4th definition at [dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/seminal?s=t):

> 4. Highly original and influencing the development of future events.

As for your other question,

> How should I ask for more time?

A better way to say this is, "I want to take one more week to learn about this".

Comment: I think it would be better to say, "I want to take one more week to learn about this," rather than "I want to take one week time."

Comment: @J.R., yes you're right. Edited.